# Unsigned types are not actually unsigned in Swift

Tags: swift, types

If you run the following code in a Swift iOS playground (XCode 7.3):

```
let delta: Int8 = -1
let result: UInt8 = UInt8(bitPattern: delta)
let test: UInt8 = UInt8.max
```

You get result == 255 and test == 255. However, if I run that code in a Swift iOS project in the Simulator the values are both -1. I also get -1 on my devices.

It doesn't appear to be limited to a single project as I can create new projects and get the same outcome.

What on earth is happening and what can I change to get unsigned types back?

Comment: Int8 value -1 is the same as UInt8 value 255. The 'U' at at the beginning stands for unsigned.  There is no way that UInt8 should ever output -1.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  Tested with both 32-bit and 64-bit devices and the playground and I'm not seeing -1 for `result` or `test`.

Comment: I tried your code and it returns 255 for both result and test

Comment: How do you check these values ?

Comment: I would like to see the code you are using to get the -1 output.

Comment: Actually, look at that guys, when I print the values, I can see they are equal to 255, but on the left panel, they appear to be -1 :
http://postimg.org/image/5zkobpwtz/

Comment: It appears to be a bug in the debugger variables display. You should submit a radar to Apple.

Comment: Gavin It looks like you are correct. If I print() the variables out to the console, I get the correct values.